# Communicate to user facebook friends (who has not yet accessed current app) via email or message

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on application which shows users friends list based on Facebook connections. User should be able to send message (via Facebook) or send email (if possible) to those user who has not yet access this app. To shows user's friends, I am using invitable_friends/taggable_friends API. This API returns id, name, picture. Since this API doesn't return email therefore I think I can't send email to user. How about sending Facebook message? What is use of "id"? Can I use "id" to communicate to user?

```
{
      "id": "HTdVs5yVQ16UYBLiKTdYWqKCnJYVHv3TSlNpgABGI5Rs1L_acCxQwEaCYJqYo93rlmeHNL8ezL-EANEDn8tmCgtG_8U7qnEVLQPkOYtYGG1Kp7",
      "name": "Dilip Kumar",
      "picture": {
        "data": {
          "is_silhouette": false,
          "url": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/c8.0.50.50/p50x50/13781923_1188731181146913_2378017407833918_8.jpg?oh=30f5e99602d65b8087efec12becd8a34&oe=585E5E66"
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: invitable_friends is for inviting users to a game with canvas, taggable_friends is for tagging. you are not supposed to use those endpoints for anything else. there is no way to get access to a friend who did not authorize your app if it´s not for inviting to a canvas game or for tagging.

Comment: My application is definitely not a game. This is social app where signed in user will see its friends list and user can invites others from its friend list to onboard and participate in discussion.

Comment: how to invite friends depending on your platform is explained in the FAQ: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq

Comment: What is use of @id return from this API?

Comment: which API exactly? if you mean invitable_friends: it´s an invite token, you don´t get any id. and you are only allowed to use it for inviting users to a game with canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sending a message to users who did not authorize your App, just use the Send Dialog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog

Sending E-Mails to users who did not authorize your App is impossible, each user has to authorize the App with the `email` permission before you can get their email.

About inviting users to an App in general: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq ("How can people invite their friends to use my app?")

Comment: As per doc, send-dialog is not supported for mobile app :-(

Comment: you can use the message dialog instead

Comment: thanks for sharing it. I am thinking to use taggable_friends and send-dialog. Hopefully it should work. I am using meteor.js therefore I believe javascript version should be fine.

Comment: taggable_friends is for tagging only, you are not allowed to use it for anything else. just open the send dialog and let the user select the recipient.

Comment: humm, I want to display the list of users (name and profile picture) in a canvas view. By looking into profile picture/name user can open send dialog  and select recipient. Is this also not supported by taggable_friends?

Comment: again, taggable_friends is for tagging only. if you just want to send a message to someone, then there is no way to preselect friends who did not authorize your app.

Comment: ok. I understand I can't preselect. The bare minimum I want is to display the name/profile picture on screen based on taggable_friends result. It will help user to see all of his friends on screen and if user want then he/she can send message (on click send message button) using send dialog by again typing the friends name. Is this use case acceptable by Facebook to use taggable_friends api?

Comment: no, of course not. again...taggable_friends is for TAGGING only. what you want to achieve is not possible and not allowed, there is no way.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am new to facebook API integration. As a developer few things looks obvious therefore re-iterated to get confirmation. Will keep send-dialog feature only then :-)